# Trouble with factoring polonomial to the 3rd degree

Tags: factoring

I am having trouble factoring this problem:
$\displaystyle{-x^{3} + 6x^{2} - 11x + 6}$

I know the answer but i can't figure out how it is done with this.
I have tried by grouping and is doesn't seem to work. Can someone show me how to do this.

Comment: That's not a "problem," it is a polynomial. The problem is factoring the polynomial. That might seem pedantic, but it is important to name things correctly in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
& -x^3+6x^2-11x+6 \\
=& -x^3+1+6x^2-11x+5 \\
=& (1-x^3)+6x^2-6x-5x+5 \\
=& (1-x)(1+x+x^2)-6x(1-x)+5(1-x) \\
=& (1-x)(1+x+x^2-6x+5) \\
=& (1-x)(x^2-5x+6) \\
=& (1-x)(x^2-2x-3x+6) \\
=& (1-x)(x(x-2)-3(x-2)) \\
=& (1-x)(x-2)(x-3)
\end{align}$$

Comment: you have an error somewhere

Comment: You may want to edit your answer after reading about [the `align` environment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5024/43351) for MathJax.

Comment: There we go. That's a lot more readable.

Comment: @Lord_Farin. Thank you I agree with with you

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to check the source, so that you can typeset your answers like this yourself in the future!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$-1 + 6 - 11 + 6 = 0$$

This method may be suggested by examining the rational roots theorem, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Big hint:

In this case, just look for zeros of the cubic polynomial, since each zero tells you a linear factor (by the [factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)).

Then try looking at factors of 6 (the constant term) - there are not many integer factors of 6 ...